# Wordpress reviews on custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have followed the tutorial on [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/adding-custom-fields-in-wordpress-comment-form/) to turn comments into reviews and it's working for me. I need the reviews only to be on my custom post type and also not on the replies. At the minute, if I click reply it will also think thats a review too.

What can I hook to test if it is the custom post and not a reply?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the Normal Comment Form It is wrapped under

```
<div id="respond" class="comment-respond"><COMMENT FORM HERE></div>
```

When reply to comment is done it is wrapped

```
<ol class="children"><div id="respond" class="comment-respond"><COMMENT FORM HERE></div></ol>
```

> These wrapping divs and HTML are from Twentyfifteen theme , please
>   check yours before going below

So In `<ol class="children">`  `.children` can be used to hide the needed  field in "Reply to Comment" form. We can make them `display:none;`

**For Example :**  If I need to make the Phone field Not displayed and Not required also,

**Step 1 :** Make this Not displayed By CSS, pass an ID to this input `<input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $phone ); ?>" class="widefat" id="user_phone"/>`

In CSS file add this :

```
ol.children form#user_phone{display:none;}
```

This will only hide the Phone field in reply to comment form, not in the normal comment.

**Step 2 :** Okay Now we have made this field hidden, but it is required field so Make this non required in PHP Script. In the "Reply to Comment" form a value of parent comment ID is also Posted when form is submitted (which is 0 in "Normal Comment" as It supposed to be parent comment :) )

```
<?php 
if($_POST['comment_parent'] != '0' || $_POST['comment_parent'] != 0 )){
    if ( ( isset( $_POST['phone'] ) ) && ( $_POST['phone'] != '') ) :
      $phone = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['phone']);
      update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'phone', $phone );
      else :
      delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'phone');
      endif;
}
?>
```

This will make the phone field hidden and also will not check for its requirement to be non-empty.